# Alternative way of accessig an array within array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to access an array within another array (basically, a two dimensional array). However, the usual way of doing this ($myarray[0][0]) doesn't work for me.
The reason is because I want to create a recursive function which, in each call, should dive deeper and deeper into a array (like, on first call it should look at $myarray[0], on second call it should look at $myarray[0][0] and so on).

Is there any alternative way of accessing an array within array?

Thanks.

Comment: pass along the sub-array as an argument so it's ALWAYS my_passed_in_array[0] no matter how deep you go.

Comment: Alternative way? I've once made a function which worked like this: `a(308)` got the `$a[3][0][8]`, and it worked since the indexes werent higher than 9. But basically there's no alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

Traverse the array by passing always a subarray of it to the recursive function.

```
function f(array &$arr)
{
    // Some business logic ...

    // Let's go into $arr[0]
    if(is_array($arr[0]))
        f($arr[0]);
}

f($myarray);
```